# Intent is asynchronous in android. Why can't it be synchronous call?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am clear with the concept of `Intent` but one thing i didn't understand is why should the `Intent` be a asynchronous message call.

Comment: Almost all in android is asynchronous )

Comment: k but why like that?@Alexey

Comment: I don't know what you mean by normal call or how you think that would even be implemented. Anything not synchronous is by definition asynchronous. Do you want your device to just freeze until an Intent is created or read? No? Then it needs to be asynchronous.

Comment: I mean normal call means synchronous call. I mean when you invoke the next activity this activity can freeze right. What is the problem if it happens.@cricket_007

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why should the Intent be a asynchronous message call.

- API calls are synchronous while intent-based invocations are
  asynchronous.
- API calls are compile time binding while intent-based calls are
  **run-time binding**.

It is basically a passive data structure holding an abstract description of an action to be performed.

> How it works?

Intents are **asynchronous** messages which allow application components to request functionality from **other Android components**. Intents allow you to interact with components from the same applications as well as with components contributed by other applications. For example, an activity can start an external activity for taking a picture.

Intents are objects of the `android.content.Intent` type. Your code can send them to the Android system defining the components you are targeting. For example, via the `startActivity()` method you can define that the intent should be used to start an activity.

An `intent` can contain data via a `Bundle`. This data can be used by the receiving component.